# Pass variable values from js function into ajax as data

Tags: javascript, ajax

I currently have javascript in place so that when a button is clicked, it fires up my modal and captures data shown on that modal to be used in AJAX (this is for a delete, so I'm showing confirmed data in the modal that will be passed to a delete function in the database).

Anyway, I log everything here and I have exactly what I need. However, I'm unsure how to pass those things into an ajax function outside of it.

Here's the js that pops up the modal and captures what I need

```
$('.deleteModal').click(function(){
    var groupingSplit = grouping.split(" - ");
        namingSplit = naming.match(/[a-z0-9]+/gi);
        number = groupingSplit[0];
        name = groupingSplit[1];
        2ndNumber = namingSplit[0];
        3rdNumber = namingSplit[1];
        referenceNumber = document.getElementById("reference").value;

    console.log(number);
    console.log(name);
    console.log(2ndNumber);
    console.log(3rdNumber);
    console.log(referenceNumber);

})
```

and outside of it I'm building ajax:

```
$("#deleteButton").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(e);

    $.ajax({
        url:'deleteFunction',
        data:{
            /*Here I need 
                number
                name
                2ndNumber
                3rdNumber
                referenceNumber
            from the other function
            */
        },
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        type:"POST",
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
             alert('Exception:', exception);
         }
    });
}
```

What is the best way I can send this data from the first function to the AJAX?

Comment: There are a lot of solutions. First of all, where do the `grouping` and `naming` variables come from in your first click handler ? If you can access them after the delete modal is clicked, you can just use them in the deletebutton click handler

Comment: So the first function grabs those values and stores them from text in the div with the modal button.

Comment: Well in that case I would either bind the click delete button at the moment I show my modal, that is, inside the delete modal click handler, or I would directly get the values from the input inside of the delete button click scope (Which is dangerous if your input values change while your modal is open, but you're in a modal so, not likely to happen)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a way to share the data between both functions.

An easy way would be to use global variables

```
let deleteData = {};

$('.deleteModal').click(function(){
    var groupingSplit = grouping.split(" - ");
        namingSplit = naming.match(/[a-z0-9]+/gi);
        number = groupingSplit[0];
        name = groupingSplit[1];
        secondNumber = namingSplit[0];
        thirdNumber = namingSplit[1];
        referenceNumber = document.getElementById("reference").value;
    deleteData = {number, name, secondNumber, thirdNumber, referenceNumber};

})
```

And then access it in the other function

```
$("#deleteButton").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(e);

    $.ajax({
        url:'deleteFunction',
        data:deleteData,
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        type:"POST",
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
             alert('Exception:', exception);
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! So if I had another ajax for an edit/update function, I could actually use the same data there as well, for a different button?

Comment: Probably.  It's hard to comment without seeing the whole code base.  It seems to me like the code from $"(#deleteButton").click should probably simply go in the $(".deleteButton") and run it from there...